# why drone ci doesn't automatically build my repo after pushing commit?

Tags: drone.io

I was trying self hosted drone CI and i have [sample repository](https://github.com/danggrianto/drone) setup for this project.

I followed all the  step to setup and it is able to show and pull the list of all my repo in github, but when i tried to make changes to drone repo nothing happen and it still show empty page with this message.

> This will be your commit stream
>
> Add a .drone.yml file and make a commit to trigger a build

I am running drone ci on virtualbox that comes with the Vagrantfile on the drone repo

Comment: Not too familiar with Drone, but if you are self hosting do you have a callback set in github to talk back to your Drone instance to inform it of the new commit and that it should go and do something?

Comment: Can you check the status of the web hook on github?  In the settings for the repo you can see recent attempts / responses to web hook payloads.  If you're behind a firewall you'll need to allow traffic from 192.30.252.0/22.

Answer (score 6):

If you configured everything properly, it may be a formatting problem with your `.drone.yml`. Drone does not give feedback on these errors and you have to check your webhook logs to discover the problem.

I'm assuming you have properly configured the webhook in your Github repo.

1. Use your browser to navigate to your Github repo, and select **Settings** tab.
2. Under settings, select **Webhooks**. You should find the webhook you configured to your self hosted Drone
3. Click on the specific webhook and at the bottom you can find the **Recent deliveries** section. This is a log of all events your repo has tried to communicate to Drone.
4. Check the response the Drone server sent you.

Comment: fyi as of drone:0.6 it displays and error message in the user interface if the yaml fails to parse

Comment: That's great to hear. Still stuck on 0.5 ;-)

Comment: This helped me get mine working.  I had misconfigured my env vars and so my Webhooks were configured `http:http://example.com/` including the double `http` and the trailing slash.  You don't want the protocol nor a trailing slash on `DRONE_RPC_HOST` nor `DRONE_SERVER_HOST`.  That was only apparent by examining the Webhook settings.